# TTImageView refresh image

Tags: three20

I have the following code

```
TTImageView* chart = [[[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,2,30, 30)] autorelease]; 
chart.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
chart.defaultImage = nil; 
chart.urlPath = @"http://test.com/test.png";
```

And I need to refresh the image, so I call reload function on the 
chart. However the chart is not refreshed. 
I found out that TTURLCache cached the image. So in app delegate when 
app just started i do the following:

```
[TTURLCache sharedCache].disableImageCache = YES; 
[[TTURLCache sharedCache] removeAll:YES];
```

However, the image is still not refreshed. Any help would be 
appreciated. I also realized that whenever I do [chart reload], and check [chart isLoading] it is always true, which means that the request is not sent somehow.

Comment: To add on to the question. I need to do this because i need to periodically update the image.

Answer (score 2):

Add a reload call after you set the URL and make sure you are calling from the main thread

```
[chart reload];
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I tried to do the following: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateChart) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; where in updateChart, i call [chart reload]. However, whenever i check [chart isLoading], it always returns me true, which means that the image is not returned. Is there something that i missed out?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer. I have found an alternative to refresh the UIImageView to replace TTImageView.
http://www.shanison.com/?p=476

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when I tried loading my users avatars into a UIButton view. I needed to use TTImageView's delegate protocol to update the button's image. For example:

```
self.avatarImageView              = [[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
self.avatarImageView.defaultImage = TTIMAGE(@"bundle://defaultAvatar.png");
self.avatarImageView.delegate     = self;
self.avatarImageView.urlPath      = @"http://www.site.com/path/to/image.png"
```

Once the urlPath is set, the request is made in the background. When you conform to the TTImageViewDelegate, you can access the following delegate methods.

```
/**
 * Called when the image begins loading asynchronously.
 */
- (void)imageViewDidStartLoad:(TTImageView*)imageView {
    NSLog(@"loading image...");
}

/**
 * Called when the image finishes loading asynchronously.
 */
- (void)imageView:(TTImageView*)imageView didLoadImage:(UIImage*)image {
    NSLog(@"loaded image!");
    [self.avatarImageButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

/**
 * Called when the image failed to load asynchronously.
 * If error is nil then the request was cancelled.
 */
- (void)imageView:(TTImageView*)imageView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"error loading image - %@", error);
}
```

When the image has loaded successfully, I can use it for my UIButton as you'll see in the imageView:didLoadImage method.

Hope this helps shed some light on this issue. I know it's an old question, but maybe it'll help others later on.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing the cache you should also reset the TTImageView. A simple way to do it would be to call [chart unsetImage] and then set the urlPath again.
Another way to do it without clearing the cache would be to add a dummy parameter to the url.

```
chart.urlPath = @"http://test.com/test.png?dummy=dummy";
```